# python prints class differently at different times

Tags: python

I have two repo where I have a dataclass defined such as

```
@dataclass
class Args:
   arg1: int
   arg2: float
   ...
```

and when I write the class to a file, I get two different behaviors. In one of the repo's it writes out the args like this...

```
args: Args(...class attributes and titles here...)
```

and in the other repo it writes out the args like this...

```
args: <class 'module_name'>
```

it is really annoying and I can't figure out why it is like this. Is there anything that would make this kind of behavior happen?

Comment: I think you need properly define your `__repr__` and `__str__`

Comment: I think you need to post an MCVE

Comment: What is a `dataclass`? It could handle things differently depending on external environment.

Comment: To confirm the former is from `print(Args)`? Not `a = Args(); print(a)`?

Comment: @blueteeth, it is the latter of your examples

Comment: @blueteeth I made mistake, your suggestion was correct but I was reading my code too fast to realize what I had written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like in one case you are printing an instance of the class, and in the other case you are printing the class.

Say you defined this class:

```
class Args:
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Args(1, 2, 3)'
```

This is a class where if you print an instance of it, you get the string `"Args(1, 2, 3)"`. Which is what you seem to get in the first instance.

```
a = Args()
print(a)
# => Args(1, 2, 3)
```

In your second instance I think you are doing this:

```
print(Args)
# => <class '__main__.Args'>
```

(when `Args` is just defined in the IDE. You'd get `'module_name'` if that's where `Args` was defined)

Comment: wow thanks for this. It seems obvious now but I was just reading my code too fast to see it. I had named the variable `args` and didn't notice I somehow typed `Args` when I was writing it to file

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, please upvote it and mark it as solved.